# Retrieving data from a DIV using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have this working code that I am using to get data from inside DIVS.

For this example, I have Fruits as a category.

I would like to get all the fruits and next to them the name of the category.

The HTML looks like this

```html
 <DIV style="HEIGHT:100%;WIDTH:100%" ID="oReportDiv">
     <DIV class="a69"> Fruits  </DIV>

     <DIV style="word-wrap:break-word;text-decoration:none;" 
          class="a92">Banana</DIV>
     <DIV style="word-wrap:break-word;text-decoration:none;" 
          class="a92">Mango</DIV>
     <DIV style="word-wrap:break-word;text-decoration:none;"  
          class="a92">Apple</DIV>
 </DIV>
```

Executing the code produces:

```
       Banana         Fruit
       Mango 
       Apple
```

But what I need is :

```
       Banana         Fruit
       Mango          Fruit
       Apple          Fruit
```

How can I achieve that?

UPDATE: I forgot to post the code

```
        t = Timer
    Do
        DoEvents
        On Error Resume Next


        Set nodeList = .document.querySelectorAll("#oReportCell .a92")
        Set nodeList1 = .document.querySelectorAll("#oReportCell .a69")

        On Error GoTo 0
        If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do

    Loop While nodeList Is Nothing

    If Not nodeList Is Nothing Then

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'This nodeList is retrieving the values inside the DIV class="a69"
        'it's a list of products
            For i = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1

              .Cells(i + 1, 1) = nodeList.Item(i).innerText

            Next
        'This nodeList1 is retrieving the value inside the DIV class="a92"
        'it's the name of the product (so only one value)
           For i = 0 To nodeList1.Length - 1

               .Cells(i + 1, 8) = nodeList1.Item(i).innerText

           Next

        End With
    End If
```

Comment: So, it appears you typed this out, but just to check, `<DIV class="a69"> Fruits  <DIV>` should actually be `<DIV class="a69"> Fruits  </DIV>`, right?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs good eye, fixed it.

Comment: So, if there's only one value, then there's no need to loop that collection, right? Why not just use the `(0)` index for each entry?

Comment: As an aside remember to post enough HTML to put your code in context and be verifiable. Your CSS selector references an id attribute of a parent element that is not visible in the HTML provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you've provided, it appears to me that you do not need to have a separate loop for your `nodeList1`. Just place in your first loop and always refer to the `0` index for `nodeList1`.

```
Dim sNode1 As String

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'This nodeList is retrieving the values inside the DIV class="a69"
    'it's a list of products

    sNode1 = NodeList1.Item(0).innerText

    For i = 0 To NodeList.Length - 1

        .Cells(i + 1, 1) = NodeList.Item(i).innerText
        .Cells(i + 1, 8) = sNode1

    Next

End With
```